# Delete document with an empty ID

Tags: couchdb

I have a CouchDB database in production. One of the documents has been edited (in Futon by an other developer).
And it's lost it's ID (don't ask me how he did it).

So now the document's id is an empty string, which makes it impossible to edit or delete via Futon.
Is there a way I could hack into CouchDB to delete that document anyway ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I couldn't delete the document. But the database itself could be deleted.
And I couldn't reproduce the bug in locale. The other developer says he just removed the _id param and saved. I don't know what happened in CouchDB when he did it. But when I do so, it only recreates a new document (as we'd expect it to do).

So I've been using [couch_docs](http://github.com/eee-c/couch_docs) to retrieve the datas locally.
As the id is empty, couch_docs doesn't imports it. So you don't even need to delete it manually.

Then I reimport all the records in an other database. I change the references to the database name in my config and everything works fine.
Destroying the database is not a problem even though there's an empty id.

Answer (score 1):

Technically, a document ID is immutable so actually *changing* the `_id` field is not directly possible. Perhaps another document was created as a copy of the first?

A bug in CouchDB 1.1.0 allowed update functions to create empty string IDs.

A [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7604557/how-do-you-delete-a-couchdb-document-with-an-empty-document-id) asks about this and I gave a walkthrough of [deleting empty ids](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7604557/how-do-you-delete-a-couchdb-document-with-an-empty-document-id/7605456#7605456) there.

Comment: No. The _id is really empty. The _all_docs returns the following : `{"id":"","key":"","value":{"rev":"1-e486474adc02feb80880ab5b1ce874d1"}}`

Comment: Yeah, I've got an empty ID in my db, too. Check it: http://isaacs.couchone.com/jsregistry/_all_docs?startkey=%22%22&endkey=%22%22&include_docs=true&show_conflicts=true

Comment: Update: The community got to the bottom of this bug and I wrote how to delete that document in a similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7604557/how-do-you-delete-a-couchdb-document-with-an-empty-document-id/7605456#7605456

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried it but [LoveSeat](http://www.russiantequila.com/wordpress/?p=119) is supposed to be able to open and edit couchedb files...

Comment: Seeing what they say, it's only an application to edit the views using the json input/output. Moreover there's zero documentation on how to install it.

Answer (score 0):

This can be caused (and fixed!) by some error checking CouchDB was missing for _update handlers, as explained in [How do you delete a couchdb document with an empty "" document id?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7604557/)